# add group header and footer to an existing group in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

[screenshot of my report-design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEIgW.png)I added a group in row-group in SSRS, but forgot to add group header and footer; then I tried to add header and footer for the created group, and I failed to find workflow option to achieve it. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thank you

Comment: can you show your report design please? It should be as simple as inserting row outside of the required group to create the group header and footer - Outside above for header outside below for footer.

Comment: Harry, thanks for responding my query; I have edited to query with the screenshot. You may please access it.

Answer (score 2):

To add headers and footer for your group, simply right on the detailed row then select Insert row, Outside group Above (for Header) and the same but Outside Group - Below for Footer

Right click here :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harry for the solution... but, in my requirement, I had to right-click with in the first cell of the first row after the header, then select "Inside Group - Above" and "Inside Group -- Below".. Thank you again for your time